# Optimality of Monte Carlo estimator

Tags: integration, probability-theory, statistics, estimation, monte-carlo

Suppose we wish to estimate the integral of a positive function $f:\mathbb{Z}_k\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ using samples from some proposal distribution $q$ over $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Importance sampling tells us that the best proposal is $q=f\big/\int f$, which is unfortunately unknown. Does there exist a better estimator for $\int f$ than the Monte Carlo estimator $\hat{f}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)/q(x_i)$ for a given fixed proposal $q$ ?

Comment: What does $|f|$ mean? I had thought it was the absolute value at first, but that doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @VarunVejalla It is the integral of $f$, sorry for the error. I edited the question.

Comment: No, not your fault. It was simply a notation I was unfamiliar with before. Would it be the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ or simply the indefinite integral?

Comment: @VarunVejalla It is a definite integral. In the question, I assume that the domain is $\mathbb{Z}_k$, so $\int f = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}_k}f(x)$.